# Refreshing Ajax Pagination instance with new data in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, real-time-updates

how to reload my table and save the current positions page in the pagination in Django?
I write one script with ajax for reloading my HTML file but my pagination crashed.

How to save current page in my JQuery file?
this is my jquery file:

> ```
> function refresh() {
>     $.ajax({
>         url: "/fax/fax_out_ajax/", // My url to need for reloading
>         success: function(data) {
>             $('#AliReload').html(data);
>         }
>     });
>     setInterval("refresh()", 3000); // reload in your time, per 1000 = 1s
> }
>
> $(function(){
>     refresh();
> });
> ```

how to pass a number of the page from HTML to javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the page number, say 5, pass it in after your url param:

```
url: "/fax/fax_out_ajax/",
data: {'page': 5},
```

If you have the page number in the variable `pageNumber`, do:

```
url: "/fax/fax_out_ajax/",
data: {'page': pageNumber},
```

If you don't already have the page number, get it from somewhere else on the page:

```
url: "/fax/fax_out_ajax/",
data: {'page': $('#page_number').val()},
```

Comment: How to pass my page url to javascript?

Comment: this is my code:
`function refresh() {
    $.ajax({
     //data: {"page": $('page_num').val()},  
        url: "/fax/fax_out_ajax/",
        data: "page=" + $('page_num').val(),
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#AliReload').html(data);
        }
    });
    setInterval("refresh()", 5000);
}
$(function(){
    refresh();
});`
with this solution url changed,but don't show data of next page,show data in page one!